# JAVA: This class has a composite primary key. It must use an ID class

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa

I have this error in my eclipse editor **This class has a composite primary key. It must use an ID class.** , but the class does not has a composite primary key, because the id is a Long

```
   @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "T_PRODUCT")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqPRODUCT", sequenceName = "SEQ_PRODUCT")
    public class Product extends ItemBase implements java.io.Serializable {

        @Id
        private Long id;


@Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 38, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqPRODUCT")
    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ..
    }
```

Comment: you have 2 id annotations in it i think?

Comment: @pandaadb it was this, please convert to answer

Comment: Is the error when building, or just in Eclipse's in-editor validation? I'm just curious, because I thought Hibernate could recognize it when it's on the setter for the same field, and just issue a warning for mixing property (getter/setter) and field access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate is seeing both annotations on the property and on the getter-method and therefore assumes that you are using a composite key.